# Count records only from left side of a LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, count, left-join

I'm building an Access query with a LEFT JOIN that, among other things, counts the number of unique sampleIDs present in the left table of the JOIN, and counts the aggregate number of specimens (bugs) present in the right table of the JOIN, both for a given group of samples (TripID). Here's the pertinent chunk of SQL code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.TripID, COUNT(t1.SampleID) AS Samples, SUM(t2.C1 + t2.C2) 
AS Bugs FROM tbl_Sample AS t1
LEFT JOIN tbl_Bugs AS t2 ON t1.SampleID = t2.SampleID
GROUP BY t1.TripID
```

The trouble I'm having is that COUNT(t1.SampleID) is not giving me my desired result. My desired result is the number of unique SampleIDs present in t1 for a given TripID (let's say 7). Instead, what I get seems to be the number of rows in t2 for which the SampleID is contained within the given TripID group (let's say 77). How can I change this SQL query to get the desired number (7, not 77)?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just take the aggregate sum first on t2, then join with t2 like this:

```
SELECT t1.TripID, COUNT(t1.SampleID) AS Samples, SUM(t3.Bugs) as Bugs
FROM tbl_Sample AS t1
LEFT Join (
  SELECT t2.SampleID, SUM(t2.C1 + t2.C2) as Bugs
  FROM tbl_Bugs as t2
  GROUP BY SampleID) AS t3 ON t1.SampleID = t3.SampleID
GROUP BY t1.TripID
```

Comment: As other answerers correctly noted, this was a tricky query and had some unnecessary clauses in it as well. I accepted this answer because I appreciated the relative simplicity and elegance of the solution, as well as the explanation of aggregating first on t2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky query, because you have different hierarchies.  Here is one method:

```
select s.tripid, count(*) as numsamples,
       (select sum(b2.c1 + b2.c2)
        from bugs b join
             tbl_sample s2
             on s2.sampleid = b.sampleid
        where s2.tripid = s.tripid
       ) as numbugs
from tbl_sample s
group by s.tripid
```

Answer (score 0):

You included a DISTINCT with a Group By. This is removing duplicates twice, which is unnecessarily complex. You can get rid of the DISTINCT.

I would have the count separate from what is going on in the group by.

```
SELECT dT.TripID
      ,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(SampleID))
          FROM Bugs B
         WHERE B.TripID = dT.TripID
       ) AS [Samples]
      ,dT.Bugs
  FROM (
        SELECT t1.TripID
              ,SUM(t2.C1 + t2.C2) AS Bugs 
          FROM tbl_Sample AS t1 
               LEFT JOIN tbl_Bugs AS t2 ON t1.SampleID = t2.SampleID
         GROUP BY t1.TripID
       ) AS dT
```